# Nested for: Outer for doesn't iterate

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I wrote a code with a `for` nested inside another `for`.
When I execute the code, the outer `for` starts with the first feature, runs as expected, then gets in the second for, runs it as expected, but then it ends. It never iterates over the first `for`.

I'm a Python beginner, every time I tried to run a `for` nested in another `for` I've found the same problem and couldn't fix or work around it so far...

For practical context:
I usually run "join by attributes" with "one to many" configuration to solve different tasks in an ISP FTTH network design department. In this case, I'm trying to classify a bunch of buildings on several streets according to the amount of flats in them. I have duplicated lines (segments of the streets where buildings are), one duplicated geometry for each lot on the street, with specific information of how many houses are inside the particular lot. I'm writing a code to count and classify the lots in a street according to how many houses exists in them (I have a general idea of how to accomplish this), but got stuck before I could begin... in the nested fors.

CODE:

```
import os # This is is needed in the pyqgis console also
import processing # This imports processing toolbox
from qgis.core import (QgsVectorLayer)# Is this is needed in the pyqgis console also?

Capa = iface.activeLayer() #TOMA EL LAYER DE EjesConHP_SinClasificar
Ejes_duplicados=Capa.getFeatures() #REFIERE A LOS ELEMENTOS INDIVIDUALES DEL LAYER

Capa.startEditing()


#CONTAR HPS INDIVIDUALES

contador=0
for eje in Ejes_duplicados:
    contador=contador+1
    print("----------contador: ",contador)
    LoteID=eje['ID']
    print("1_ Lote id: ",LoteID)
    Clase_Lote=eje['LOTE_CLASS']
    print("2_ Clase Lote: ",Clase_Lote)
    HP=eje['HP']
    print("3_ HP en Lote:",HP)
    EjeID=eje['E_ID']
    print("4_ Eje ID:",EjeID)    
    if Clase_Lote == NULL:
        print("--CLASE=NULL")
        for eje2 in Ejes_duplicados:
            Lote2ID=eje2['ID']
            print("5_ Lote2 id: ",Lote2ID)
            Eje2ID=eje2['E_ID']
            print("6_ Eje ID:",Eje2ID)
```

CONSOLE:

```
exec(open('C:/Users/Javier.Ibanez/OneDrive - American Tower/HW/GPON/Moreno/Anteproyecto/HP POR EJE_LOTES/SCRIPTS/COUNT AND CLASSIFY HP AND MDU.py'.encode('utf-8')).read())
----------contador:  1
1_ Lote id:  6
2_ Clase Lote:  NULL
3_ HP en Lote: 22
4_ Eje ID: 1
--CLASE=NULL
5_ Lote2 id:  1
6_ Eje ID: 1
5_ Lote2 id:  2
6_ Eje ID: 1
5_ Lote2 id:  3
6_ Eje ID: 1
5_ Lote2 id:  5
6_ Eje ID: 1
5_ Lote2 id:  4
6_ Eje ID: NULL
5_ Lote2 id:  7
6_ Eje ID: NULL
5_ Lote2 id:  8
6_ Eje ID: NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Capa.getFeatures()` in each loop without assigning a variable(`Ejes_duplicados`)

```
contador = 0
for eje in Capa.getFeatures(): # <<<
    contador = contador+1
    print("----------contador: ", contador)
    LoteID = eje['ID']
    print("1_ Lote id: ", LoteID)
    Clase_Lote = eje['LOTE_CLASS']
    print("2_ Clase Lote: ", Clase_Lote)
    HP = eje['HP']
    print("3_ HP en Lote:", HP)
    EjeID = eje['E_ID']
    print("4_ Eje ID:", EjeID)

    if Clase_Lote == NULL:
        print("--CLASE=NULL")

        for eje2 in Capa.getFeatures(): # <<<
            Lote2ID = eje2['ID']
            print("5_ Lote2 id: ", Lote2ID)
            Eje2ID = eje2['E_ID']
            print("6_ Eje ID:", Eje2ID)
```